# Checking if a cell of matrices is a subset of another cell of matrices

Tags: matlab, cells

I've simplified this problem from another post. Define A and B as below

```
A = {[1 1 1],[2 3 3]}

B = {[1 1 1],[2 3 3],[3 3 2]}
```

A is a 1x2 cell of two arrays; B is a 1x3 cell containing three arrays.

I'm trying to write a piece of code that takes A and B as input, and outputs a 1 if A is a member of B (which it is in the above example) and a 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**

⓵  Take the [**`transpose`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) of **`A`** and **`B`**.

⓶  Convert them into matrices using [**`cell2mat`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

⓷  Use [**`ismember`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to determine row by row if **`A`** is a member of **`B`** or not

⓸ Use [**`all`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) to determine if all rows of **`A`** are in **`B`** or not.

**Code:**

```
A = cell2mat(A.');   B = cell2mat(B.');
output = ismember(A,B,'rows');
output = all(output)
```

**One-liner Code:** 

You can write the above in one-line as:  `all(ismember(cell2mat(A.'), cell2mat(B.'),'rows'))`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Sardar_Usama for a solution. I have also come up with an alternate solution in the meantime.

```
Acell = cellfun(@mat2str,A,'UniformOutput',false)
Bcell = cellfun(@mat2str,B,'UniformOutput',false)
isAsubsetOfB = all(ismember(Acell,Bcell))
```